# How to connect rfid reader to raspberry pi using wifi?

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi2, rfid

I am working on a tracking project.
I want to connect several rfid reader(any reader HF,UHF) to Raspberry pi using wifi. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your reader and its capabilities.
Usually readers have Ethernet port but does not support wifi by their own.

1. So your first task is to connect reader to pc using Ethernet cable and make it work as you like.
2. Then you need to make your program work on raspberry pi.
3. Finally you can plug your reader to wifi router. Connect Pi to the same network using wifi dongle and here you go, you have wireless reader.